# Modifying view on fullcalendar to have days on y axis and times on x axis in the style of agendaWeek view

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, fullcalendar, extend

I have been trying to modify the code to make a change to arshaw's full calendar. I basically want to have an agendaWeek view but have to 2 axis swapped so the days run down the y-axis and the times are across the header section of the table. If anyone could point me in the right direction to start this it would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is an answer for this request: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32781403/1163786