# Customizing the agendaWeek view of Full Calender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to customize the agendaWeek view of full calender, by swapping the axes. Currently the seven days of the week are displayed on the top and the time slots (12 am to 11:59 pm) are displayed on the left. I want to swap the positions.

Basically I want to create a school timetable by doing this.

Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the agendaWeek view of Full Calender to swap the axes.
It only displays one or more columns with time slots running vertically, see [source](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/agenda/AgendaView.js#L2). The feature your are looking for is simply not implemented on the agendWeek view.

> Any pointers on how to do this?

One would need to extend Full Calendar and add a new View, e.g. `agendaWeekAxesSwapped` and they did because of a feature request:

A new view, like Agenda view, but with axis flipped
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/1753

The new view is called "timeline" and is available as a commercial addon:
http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/

#### How to get started?

When you read the license you will see, that it has a "Non-Commercial Creative Commons" for schools and universities:
http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/license/

That means you can simply download and use the Free Trial version, when you fall under the CC-license, as described here: http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/download/

---

#### Alternative: jquery-timetable

Maybe you can switch to another JS package.

A good, but not well maintained alternative for a school timetable is jQuery Timetable.

- https://github.com/holygeek/jquery-timetable
- http://www.jadualsekolah.com/demo/

Comment: Coding a view from scratch is a lot of work, from what fullcalender source code looks like. I am under a deadline, is there any other plugin I can use?

Comment: The scheduler of full calender is still not the one I am wanting to use. I am also trying to avoid coding a custom view

Comment: I've added jquery-timetable as an alternative solution. Its not well maintained, but maybe sufficient for this job.